# Custom Taxonomy Meta Admin Column

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I've added a custom taxonomy - shop_departments which is hierarchal.  I've then added a meta field to this new taxonomy - term_meta[front_page] - which is all working fine.

However, on the management screen for the taxonomy I want a column for this meta data so the user can see at a glance which departments are assigned to the front page.

I can't work out how to add a column to this page.  I want to do something like:

```
// Register the column
function front_page_column_register( $columns ) {
$columns['front-page'] = __( 'Front Page', 'my-plugin' );

return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shopp_department_columns', 'front_page_column_register' );
```

Any help would be great, all the articles i've found talk about adding it to a posts or custom post-type edit page, not the taxonomy page itself!

Comment: I don't see a filter available in the `get_columns()` method for `WP_Terms_List_Table` class, so unless I am mistaken, I don't think it is possible. This would be a cool feature though. Heck, I'd add it myself if WordPress would ever switch to github. I'm useless on the SVN system.

Comment: I disagree, it must be possible.  That filter i've posted above is described  [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-id-column-to-custom-taxonomy-admin-display-1) and used in the plugin [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) but for some reason it's not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to work it out.  Seems like the filters only work when wrapped in an 'admin_init' action.  My final code to add an admin column for the custom taxonomy meta 'front_page' to the custom taxonomy 'shopp_department' in my themes' functions.php

```
// Register the column
function department_add_dynamic_hooks() {
$taxonomy = 'shopp_department';
add_filter( 'manage_' . $taxonomy . '_custom_column', 'department_taxonomy_rows',15, 3 );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $taxonomy . '_columns',  'department_taxonomy_columns' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'department_add_dynamic_hooks' );

function department_taxonomy_columns( $original_columns ) {
$new_columns = $original_columns;
array_splice( $new_columns, 1 );
$new_columns['frontpage'] = esc_html__( 'Front Page', 'taxonomy-images' );
return array_merge( $new_columns, $original_columns );
}

function department_taxonomy_rows( $row, $column_name, $term_id ) {
$t_id = $term_id;
$meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
if ( 'frontpage' === $column_name ) {
    if ($meta == true) {
        return $row . 'Yes';
    } else {
        return $row . 'No';
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps someone.